# Proving law of cosines

Tags: complex-analysis

For $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$. How can I use this result: $$|z-w|^2=|z|^2+|w|^2-2 \Re(z \bar w)$$ to prove the law of cosines?

$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab \cos \theta$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) In the complex plane if you draw z, w, and z-w you get a triangle with the lengths of the corresponding sides being |z|, |w|, and |z-w|. Call these length a, b, c.

(2) consider the real part of $z\bar w$ with z and w expressed in r, $\theta$ format. $z= r_z(cos \theta_z + i sin \theta_z)$ and $\bar w = r_w(cos \theta_w - i sin \theta_w)$ so $\Re(z\bar w) = r_z r_w (cos \theta_z cos \theta_w + sin \theta_z sin \theta_w ) = r_z r_w cos (\theta_z - \theta_w )$

(3) $(\theta_z - \theta_w )$ is the angle between w and z, say $\theta$. Also, $r_z$ and $ r_w$ are equal correspondingly to |z| and |w|. So given $|z-w|^2=|z|^2+|w|^2-2 \Re(z \bar w)$ and putting this together with (1) and (2)...

(4) $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab \cos \theta$

Answer (score 1):

Express the complex numbers in polar form.